# Importaddress and conf

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli, bitcoin.conf

I'm wondering if its possible to add imported addresses into the bitcoin conf file.

So, rather than calling the cli with `importaddress`, I would add the address to the conf file, with say, `importaddress=1123345678A`

Is this supported in the conf file?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `importaddress` is supported in config file. I use https://jlopp.github.io/bitcoin-core-config-generator/ for making changes in config file

I don't see any options to solve this problem here: https://github.com/jlopp/bitcoin-core-config-generator/blob/0febd7537a89846e0b40badca12d3b7dd2074dfc/src/data.json

There are only two options related to "import" mentioned in the above file:
`loadblock` - Imports blocks from external blk000??.dat file on startup. This option can be set multiple times with different file values.
`stopafterblockimport` - Stop running after importing blocks from disk.

`importaddress` adds an address or script (in hex) that can be watched as if it were in your wallet but cannot be used to spend as mentioned here: https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/importaddress/